# Multiple subequations and equations in a single align environment

Tags: align

I have three equations in an `align` environment which I'd like to be numbered as follows: `(1a)`, `(1b)`, `(2)` [The numbers are just indicative; I don't want them to be exactly 1 and 2]

With `subequations` I can easily get the numbering `(1a)`, `(1b)`, `(1c)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        \mathbf{a} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                    a_1\\
                    \vdots \\
                    a_2
                \end{bmatrix} \label{eq:1a} \\        
        &= \left[ a_1 \ \ldots \ a_2 \right]^\mathrm{T} \label{eq:1b}\\
        %
        \mathbf{b} &= \left[ b_1 \ldots \b_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}, \label{eq:2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
%


\end{document}
```

Using some code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80134/nesting-subequations-within-align), I can increase by one the third equation number, obtaining `(1a)`, `(1b)`, `(2a)`, but that's still not what I want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewenvironment{subequations}[1][]{%              optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
%  \def\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}% we patched it already :)
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%    parentequation = equation
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         (sub)equation  = 0
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \let\parentlabel\label%                           Evade sanitation performed by amsmath
  \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%               #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%    equation = subequation
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand*{\nextParentEquation}[1][]{%            optional argument: label-name for (first) parent equation
  \refstepcounter{parentequation}%                  parentequation++
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%                         equation = 0
  \ifx\\#1\\\relax\else\parentlabel{#1}\fi%         #1 given: \label{#1}, otherwise: nothing
}

\begin{document}
%%
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        \mathbf{a} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                    a_1\\
                    \vdots \\
                    a_2
                \end{bmatrix} \label{eq:1a} \\        
        &= \left[ a_1 \ \ldots \ a_2 \right]^\mathrm{T} \label{eq:1b}\\ \nextParentEquation
        %
        \mathbf{b} &= \left[ b_1 \ \ldots \ b_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}, \label{eq:2}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
%%


\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to modify the code to obtain exactly `(1a)`, `(1b)`, `(2)`?

Comment: I think that this is essentially the same question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313367/block-of-equations-with-only-some-being-subequations Do you agree?

Comment: Dang it! Yes, that seems to be what I need. Sorry I couldn't find it before posting and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can we close this one?

Comment: I tried to use the solution from the other question in a MWE and it works, but if I try to use it in the document where I need it, it doesn't work anymore and outputs [![this][1]][1]
Any idea of any package that could be causing the clash?
Otherwise I'll try to fiddle around with the different packages I'm using.

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tvx05.png

Comment: Did you run LaTeX twice? Anyway, since the code there does the job, it's better to close this question as duplicate. Try and make a minimal example that fails and open a new question.

Comment: Yes, I did run LaTeX twice.

I tried to remove the packages one by one and the problem arises when I include `cleveref`

Comment: Please, ask a new question, then. I can see that the code may conflict with `cleveref`. Having a real example can help solve the problem.

Comment: Ok. Will do that. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think I have a solution.