# Block of equations with only some being subequations and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, align, cleveref

I recently [asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318109) regarding the numbering of a block of equations within an `align` environment of which only some should be numbered as subequations; in my case I had three equations that I wanted to be numbered `(1a)`, `(1b)`, `(2)`.

I was pointed to an already proposed solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313367/block-of-equations-with-only-some-being-subequations), which I tested and it is indeed working, but I found out that this solution fails when including the `cleveref` package. Here you can see the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{cleveref} % Comment/uncomment to see the difference

\makeatletter
\newcounter{manualsubequation}
\renewcommand{\themanualsubequation}{\alph{manualsubequation}}
\newcommand{\startsubequation}{%
  \setcounter{manualsubequation}{0}%
  \refstepcounter{equation}\ltx@label{manualsubeq\theequation}%
  \xdef\labelfor@subeq{manualsubeq\theequation}%
}
\newcommand{\tagsubequation}{%
  \stepcounter{manualsubequation}%
  \tag{\ref{\labelfor@subeq}\themanualsubequation}%
}
\let\subequationlabel\ltx@label
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    % With 2 elements
    \startsubequation\subequationlabel{eq:prefyk}
    a &= \begin{bmatrix}
                                a_1 \\
                                \vdots \\
                                a_2
                            \end{bmatrix} 
    \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefyka}                            \\
    &= \left[ a_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! a_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}     \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefykb}\\
    b &= \left[ b_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! b_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}, \label{eq:prefe}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If the line `\usepackage{cleveref}` is included, the result is the following.

[image: Wrong numbering]

Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: Looking at the construction of the references I am not sure this is the best way, actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some changes need to be done with `cleveref`, because it modifies several things under the hood.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{manualsubequation}
\renewcommand{\themanualsubequation}{\alph{manualsubequation}}
\newcommand{\startsubequation}{%
  \setcounter{manualsubequation}{0}%
  \refstepcounter{equation}\ltxcref@label{manualsubeq\theequation}%
  \xdef\labelfor@subeq{manualsubeq\theequation}%
}
\newcommand{\tagsubequation}{%
  \stepcounter{manualsubequation}%
  \tag{\ref{\labelfor@subeq}\themanualsubequation}%
}
\newcommand\ltxcref@label[1]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}
    {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  % also do the cleveref label
  \protected@write\@auxout{}
    {\string\newlabel{#1@cref}{{\cref@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
}
\let\subequationlabel\ltxcref@label
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
% With 2 elements
\startsubequation\subequationlabel{eq:prefyk}
  a &= \begin{bmatrix}
       a_1 \\
       \vdots \\
       a_2
       \end{bmatrix}
  \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefyka}
\\
    &= \left[ a_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! a_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}
       \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefykb}
\\
  b &= \left[ b_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! b_2 \right]^\mathrm{T},
\label{eq:prefe}
\end{align}

Let's see the next number
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

Also references: \eqref{eq:prefe}, \eqref{eq:prefyka} and \eqref{eq:prefykb}

\cref{eq:prefykb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This works fine.
As a related note, I tried to call the references with `cleveref` using `\cref{eq:prefyka,eq:prefykb,eq:prefe}`, which should produce the string `eq. (1a), (1b) and (2)`, but for some reason it produced the string `eq (2), (1a) and (1b)`.

Anyway, that is not a problem for me, at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `cleveref` redefines `\label` to have an optional argument which may be given to override the type of the label. In this case the `\ltx@label` must fail unless the type is given, i.e. subequation.

In order to use the full `cleveref` support, provide the `\crefname` names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{manualsubequation}
\renewcommand{\themanualsubequation}{\alph{manualsubequation}}
\newcommand{\startsubequation}{%
  \setcounter{manualsubequation}{0}%
  \refstepcounter{equation}\ltx@label[subequation]{manualsubeq\theequation}%
  \xdef\labelfor@subeq{manualsubeq\theequation}%
}
\newcommand{\tagsubequation}{%
  \refstepcounter{manualsubequation}%
  \tag{\ref{\labelfor@subeq}\themanualsubequation}%
}
\let\subequationlabel\ltx@label
\makeatother


\usepackage{cleveref} % Comment/uncomment to see the difference



\crefname{subequation}{subequation}{subequations}
\Crefname{subequation}{Subequation}{Subequations}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    % With 2 elements
    \startsubequation\subequationlabel{eq:prefyk}
    a &= \begin{bmatrix}
                                a_1 \\
                                \vdots \\
                                a_2
                            \end{bmatrix} 
    \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefyka}                            \\
    &= \left[ a_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! a_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}     \tagsubequation\label{eq:prefykb}\\
    b &= \left[ b_1 \quad\!\! \ldots \quad\!\! b_2 \right]^\mathrm{T}, \label{eq:prefe}
\end{align}

In \cref{manualsubeq1} we saw that


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine, too. Thanks @Christian Hupfer.

As for the other solution, I tried to call the references with `cleveref` using `\cref{eq:prefyka,eq:prefykb,eq:prefe}`, which should produce the string `eq. (1a), (1b) and (2)`, but for some reason it produced the string `eq (2), (1a) and (1b)`.

Anyway, that is not a problem for me, at the moment ;)